# How can I check whether an array parameter is empty?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to select users from a database with Doctrine and Symfony. Depending on whether I have a supplied list of user IDs I want to only select users with these IDs. If the list is empty, then all users should be selected.

Here is the code I have created so far:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function selectUsers (array $userIds) {
        $dql = "
            SELECT
                u
            FROM
                MyBundle:User
            WHERE
                u.id IN (:users)"; // OR (:users) does not contain any values

        $query = $this
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter("users", $userIds);

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

How can I check whether the array is empty? So far, I have tried `IS EMPTY`, `= ()`, `= []`, `SIZE(:users) = 0`, `COUNT(:users) = 0` but all of them give me errors. What is the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically build DQL query

```
public function selectUsers(array $userIds)
{
    $dql = "SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User";
    $params = array();
    if ($users) {
        $dql .= " WHERE u.id IN (:users)";
        $params["users"] = $userIds;
    }
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql)->execute($params);
}
```

You are building two different queries - select all, select specific users. I think you cannot build such SQL query. Maybe DQL has some shortcut how you can do it, but I would prefer SQL-ish syntax.

Comment: I would really like to avoid building the query dynamically. The query I posted here is only a sample query, the actual query is much bigger. Splitting it into several parts makes it even harder to understand what is going on.

Comment: @Chris: if you put logic, wherever you put it, understanding will be "difficult". To me this solution is either readable and understandable better than a complex query where, for instance, you select all id(s) if array is empty.

Comment: @Chris: You or Doctrine in the background must build query dynamically because SQL isn't ready for such queries. `WHERE u.id IN ()` causes syntax error. I haven't find such DQL operator so I think that you have to somehow build it.

Comment: `WHERE u.id IN (:users)` actually works fine, even if the supplied array is empty. The problem is that it will never be true if the array is empty. This is why I need an additional condition that is always true if the array is empty.

Comment: I understand the problem, I talked about SQL (Postgres, MySQL throws syntax error). I tried to say that it will always be tradeoff.
It's up to you what solution is best for you. If you don't like dynamic builder then I think `userCount` is good enough. If you have test that covers both cases than final DQL query is just implementation detail.

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I have come up with so far is to calculate the count in PHP and pass it in as an additional parameter.

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function selectUsers (array $userIds) {
        $dql = "
            SELECT
                u
            FROM
                MyBundle:User
            WHERE
                u.id IN (:users) OR :userCount = 0";

        $query = $this
            ->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->setParameter("users", $userIds)
            ->setParameter("userCount", count($userIds));

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

However, I have a hard time believing that this is impossible to do directly in DQL.